# Typescript binding to Knockout observable not changing selected value

Tags: json, knockout.js, typescript

In my typescript view model class I have the following structure for a property:

```
  objectChecks = {
        objVal: {
            customerValue: ko.observable(null),
            exportValue: ko.observable(null),
            myTimestamp1: ko.observable(null),
            rfqStatusValue: ko.observable(null),
            rfqCommentValue: ko.observable(null),
            myTimestamp2: ko.observable(null),
            termConditionValue: ko.observable(null),
            indemnityValue: ko.observable(null),
            myTimestamp3: ko.observable(null),
            quoteOCMValue: ko.observable(null),
            //checkpointValue: ko.observable(null),
            dtReasonValue: ko.observable(null),
            myTimestamp4: ko.observable(null)
        },
        objCom: {
            termCondCommentValue: ko.observable(null),
            quoteComm: ko.observable(null),
            // checkpointComm: ko.observable(null),        
        }
    };
```

After I save this, as a json into a field, I cannot change in the UI the values, is like the system updated to the saved value from cache memory.

Save json Data:

```
  var self = this;
    //self.objectChecks;
    // format json to ignore null values
    var json = ko.toJSON(self.objectChecks, function (key, value) {
        if (value == null || key === "__ko_mapping__" || key === "__proto__") {
            return;
        }
        else if (value == "") {
            return;
        }
        else {
            return value;
        }
    });
```

Load from Json:

```
var jsonFormat = this.commentsAction.replace(/&#34;/g, '"').replace(/&#40;/g, '(').replace(/&#41;/g, ')').replace(/\r\n/g, '\\r\\n').replace(/\t/g, '\\\\t').replace(/&#39;/g, "'").replace(/&#35;/g, '#').replace(/&#36/g, '$').replace(/&#37;/g, '%').replace(/&#38;/g, '&').replace(/&#42;/g, '*').replace(/&#43;/g, '+').replace(/&#44;/g, ',').replace(/&#45;/g, '-').replace(/&#46;/g, '.').replace(/&#47;/g, '/');
        ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonFormat, {}, this.objectChecks);
```

View Sample:

```
<tr>
                <td class="fl"><p>Terms & Conditions?</p></td>
                <td class="fv"><select class="inputControlFlexControl" data-bind="options: termConditionField, value: objectChecks.objVal.termConditionValue, optionsCaption: 'Select...', event:{change: saveButton}"></select><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-help" style="display:inline" /></td>

                <td><!--used only for structure--></td>

                <td class="fl flu"><p>Requirement?</p></td>
                <td class="fv fvu"><select class="inputControlFlexControl" data-bind="options: nuclearIndemnity, value: objectChecks.objVal.indemnityValue, optionsCaption: 'Select...', event:{change: saveButton}"></select><span class="myQuestCs" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <!-- <tr data-bind="visible: check13Selection()">-->
                <td class="fl flu"><p>Comments</p></td>
                <td class="fv fvu"><textarea class="iled inlineMLTxtEditorLinHeight" data-bind="value: objectChecks.objCom.termCondCommentValue, event:{change: saveButton}" style="width: 50%" /></td>
            </tr>
```

Any idea what might generate this issue?

Upon testing I found that the issue comes from the "Load from Json:" method as that runs after I change the value and updated to the value saved on the server, so I will add a flag to don't run that again?

Comment: how come select tag dont have optionsValue or optionsText at-least . more clarity on what you looking is appreciated & fiddle is more than welcome to show up your issue

Comment: Hey, I've not added the entire code, my bad, as this made to be unclear. Do you think that what I've done to avoid this issue is ok, or you would recommend something else?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add a property used as a flag, because this will restrict to take the saved value from the server each time:

```
saveFlag = ko.observable(0);
if (this.saveFlag() === 0) {
        var jsonFormat = this.commentsAction.replace(/&#34;/g, '"').replace(/&#40;/g, '(').replace(/&#41;/g, ')').replace(/\r\n/g, '\\r\\n').replace(/\t/g, '\\\\t').replace(/&#39;/g, "'").replace(/&#35;/g, '#').replace(/&#36/g, '$').replace(/&#37;/g, '%').replace(/&#38;/g, '&').replace(/&#42;/g, '*').replace(/&#43;/g, '+').replace(/&#44;/g, ',').replace(/&#45;/g, '-').replace(/&#46;/g, '.').replace(/&#47;/g, '/');
        ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonFormat, {}, this.objectChecks);
        this.preOrderChecks(true);
        this.saveFlag(1);
        $("#BTN_TB_TaskForm_MarkAsCompleted").hide();
        if (epmcrm.step === '') {
            this.stepStatus('Compliance Pre-Qualification');
        }
    }
    else if (this.saveFlag() === 1) {
        $("#BTN_TB_TaskForm_MarkAsCompleted").hide();
        this.preOrderChecks(true);
    }
```